# in angular 17 generate the open or close tag for descriptionlist separate?

Tags: angular17

I need to generate an open or close tag for a description list with angular 17
in a for next loop.

I want to loop over an objects with keyValue pipe. If the value is a string then I need to generate html with a DT for the key and a DD tag for the value. When the next value is an object or the value is the last one and a string value, I need to close the DL tag. When the previous value is an object or it is the first and string value then I start the DL tag. But when I create the html template, eslint tells me there is no opening tag with my closing tag. How can I prevent this linting error to show up? or how to how do i create a dl is angular when i iterate over an object like this {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: {a:value3}}

Answer (score 0):

After consideration how angular works with templates inserting dom elements, I think a way to achieve this is to convert the object to an array where y collect all adjacent non objectvalue sibling inside an array. Like [[{key1: value1}, {key2: value2}],{key3: {a:value3}},[{key4: value4}]]
From {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: {a:value3}, key4: value4}
Then you iterate over the array and when the value is an array you create the dl iterate over the objects and create for each key a dt and value a dd tag.